# CAST para valor monetário armazenado em texto no MySQL

Tags: mysql, conversão-de-tipo

Na tabela de produtos do banco existe um campo `valor` que possui o tipo `varchar(255)`

Observe a consulta :

**Consulta**

```
SELECT
valor                        as valor_original,
CAST(valor AS DECIMAL(18,2)) as valor_convertido
from
produtos
```

**Resultado**

```
valor_original | valor_convertido

170,00           170.00
204,80           204.00
447,95           447.00
170,00           170.00
209,00           209.00
230,40           230.00
139,00           139.00
209,00           209.00
315,00           315.00
230,40           230.00
170,00           170.00
```

Como posso realizar uma consulta realizando a conversão em `decimal`
sem perder a precisão dos valores ?

Comment: você deseja fazer um `where` com o `valor_convertido`?

Comment: Não uma select simples mesmo com ele convertido. Consegui resolver @VirgilioNovic agradeço sua atenção !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui resolver usando o [Replace](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replace.html) juntamente ao [CAST](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html)

**Consulta**

```
SELECT
valor                          AS valor_original,
CAST(REPLACE(valor, ',', '.')  AS DECIMAL(18,2)) as valor_convertido
from
produtos
```

**Resultado**

```
valor_original | valor_convertido
170,00           170.00
204,80           204.80
447,95           447.95
170,00           170.00
209,00           209.00
230,40           230.40
139,00           139.00
209,00           209.00
315,00           315.00
230,40           230.40
170,00           170.00
```

Comment: eu acho que só com um replace se pode problemas se os valores passarem para milhar então eu faria: `CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(valor, '.', ''),',','.') AS DECIMAL(18,2)) as valor_convertido` evitaria o problema.